# SQL Count results

Tags: sql

```
select distinct
LsPO AS 'PO Listed',
LsSuID AS 'Supplier ID',
LSShipSpeed AS 'Ship Speed',
count('PO Listed') as 'PO Count'
From csn_order..TblLoadShipping
where 
datalength(LSPO) = '10' 
and LsDateLoaded >= DATEADD(day,-1, GETDATE())
and lspo like 'CS%'
and lsshipspeed is not null
group by lspo, lssuid, lsshipspeed
order by 'PO Listed' desc
```

In PO Listed, I get a PO one time, but the PO Count column is still giving me the result of 141, counting the number of instances that PO had prior to either the where or the distinct filters.

Maybe Im going about this entirely the wrong way.

Here are some results:

```
CS89980125  14347   153 1
CS89980122  22471   1   1
CS89980113  420 153 1
CS89980113  420 GR  1
```

Id like the last column, the counts, to indicate that CS89980113    is appearing twice

Comment: your query have no sense in sql  .. try show a real case or a correct sql query  .. please

Comment: Please provide some sqlfiddle

Comment: I updated the original post to just have my exact script in there.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the number of not null value for a column, you can use

```
select count(your_col1)
from your_table
```

if you need  the relative count of not null value for a column respect a second column you can use

```
select your_col2, count(your_col1)
from your_table 
group by your_col2
```

if you use in group by the same column you use in count you simply don't get a group by  ..

if you need   count of distinct value  you  can add  distinct in `count(distinct your_col1)` function

based on you sample you can't use alias  in select clause   so  you can't use

```
count('PO Listed') as 'PO Count'
```

but you should use

```
  count(LsPO ) as 'PO Count'
```

and for distinct value you should use

```
   count(distinct LsPO ) as 'PO Count'
```

Comment: So I tried addint the distinct into the count and Im now getting these as results.

`CS89790849 14695 GR 1`

`CS89790848 11898 FDHD 1`

`CS89790847 33430 1 1`

`CS89790847 33430 GR 1`

Sorry about formatting, I dont think I can make the result look good here. Anyways, CS89790847 appears twice, Id like to make count show 2 for that.

Comment: you comment is not clear (and the sql you provided in question is wrong also )  ... anyway i have updated the asnwer  with other suggestion